# Flutter Firebase: data updating in Firebase, but not showing the counter update on the screen automatically

Tags: firebase, flutter, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

I am holding a counter in my Firebase which holds the total upvotes for a picture. When the upvote button is pressed, the database should update the counter of that specified counter by 1, which it does. However, it doesn't show the update on the app screen. For example if an image has 8 upvotes, and the button is pressed to upvote, it will still show 8 upvotes on the screen but in the database it will now be 9 upvotes. When I hot refresh the value changes. How can I make both things happen asynchronously? I tried playing around with it and it's always that either it updates the database and the screen stays unchanged, or the screen changes and the database doesn't.

For the functions below, they behave as expected but just not asynchronously on the screen.

**The relevant function that increments the followers in the database:**

```
// likedposts is a list of posts that have already been liked and is initalised earlier
// even if I remove the if statement here, the behaviour is the same
void incrementFollowers(int index) async {
  if (!likedposts.contains(posts[index])) { 
  likedposts.add(posts[index]);
  addLikedPost();
  FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('uploads')
    .doc(usernames[index])
    .collection('images')
    .where('caption', isEqualTo: captions[index])
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach((result) async { 
          FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('uploads')
          .doc(usernames[index])
          .collection('images')
          .doc(result.id)
          .update({'upvotes': upvotes[index]+1,});  
          setState(() {
            getUpvotes(index);
          });
      });
    });
   }
  }
```

**The function that displays the upvotes:**

```
getUpvotes(int index) {
    return RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
          style:
              TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20.0),
          children: <TextSpan>[
          TextSpan(
          text: upvotes[index].toString() + ' upvotes',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
          recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
            ..onTap = () {
              print(
                  'This will take to upvoters of the photo');
            }),
      ]));
  }
```

**The widget that displays everything in my app (to find where I'm calling the incrementFollowers button, just do ctrl+F for incrementFollowers and you'll find it):**

```
Widget _getPost() {
    
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    if (url!= null) {
    return new ListView.builder(
        itemCount: images.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int userIndex) {
          
          return Container(
            child: Column(
            
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                 
                //Includes dp + username + report flag
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8),
                            child: GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                  context, 
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => UserProfile(usernames[userIndex])
                                    ),
                                  );
                                },
                                child: CircleAvatar(
                                  backgroundImage: displayPic[1],
                                ))),
                        RichText(
                          text: TextSpan(children: <TextSpan>[
                            TextSpan(
                                text: usernames[userIndex],
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15.0),
                                recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                                  ..onTap = () {
                                    Navigator.push(
                                      context, 
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) => UserProfile(usernames[userIndex])
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  })
                          ]),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    
                   IconButton(
                    icon: Image.asset('assets/pictures/ICON_flag.png'),
                    iconSize: 25,
                    onPressed: () {
                      reportUser(userIndex, context);
                
                    },
                  ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Stack(children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                    //the post picture
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      
                      //This is to handle the tagged users raised button
                      onTap: () {
                        if (isVisible == false)
                          setState(() {
                            isVisible = true;
                          });
                        else
                          setState(() {
                            isVisible = false;
                          });
                          
                      },
                    ),
                    height: size.height * 0.5,
                    width: returnWidth(),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 16,
                    right: 16,
                    top: 0,
                    bottom: 24,
                  ),
                    // constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 50),
                   
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                         

                          fit: BoxFit.fill, image: NetworkImage(images[userIndex])),
                    )
                    
                    ),
                Positioned(
                  
                    top: 25,
                    left: 50,
                    child: returnTaggedUsers(userIndex),)
              ]),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: returnAlignment(),
                // upvote + downvote + comment + send + save icons
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    color: upVoted ? Colors.blue : Colors.white,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8),
                      child: IconButton(
                        icon: Image.asset('assets/pictures/ICON_upvote.png'),
                        iconSize: 25,
                        onPressed: () async {
                          setState(() {
                            incrementFollowers(userIndex); 
                            
                          }); 
                          getUpvotes(userIndex);
                        },
                      )

                  ),
                  Container(
                      color: downVoted ? Colors.blue : Colors.white,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8),
                      child: IconButton(
                        icon: Image.asset('assets/pictures/ICON_downvote.png'),
                        iconSize: 25,
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            
                            downVoted = true;
                            upVoted = false;                         
                          });
                        },

                      )),
                  Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8),
                      child: IconButton(
                        icon: Image.asset('assets/pictures/ICON_comment.png'),
                        iconSize: 25,
                        onPressed: () {
                         commentPopUp(userIndex, context);
                        },
                      )),
                  Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8),
                      child: IconButton(
                        icon: Image.asset('assets/pictures/ICON-send.png'),
                        iconSize: 25,
                        onPressed: () {
                          print(
                              'This will let a user send the post to another user');
                        },
                      )),
                  Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8),
                      child: IconButton(
                        icon: Image.asset('assets/pictures/ICON_save.png'),
                        iconSize: 25,
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context, 
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => ReportPanel()
                              ),
                            );
                        },
                      )),
                      
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: returnAlignment(),
                //This column contains username, upload description and total upvotes
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    
                    //The person who posted along with photo description
                    alignment: returnCommentAlignment(),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                    child: RichText(
                        text: TextSpan(
                            style:
                                TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20.0),
                            children: <TextSpan>[
                          TextSpan(
                              text: usernames[userIndex] + ': ',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                              recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                                ..onTap = () {
                                  Navigator.push(
                                      context, 
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) => UserProfile(usernames[userIndex])
                                      ),
                                    );
                                }),
                          TextSpan(text: captions[userIndex]),
                        ])),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    //The total upvotes of post
                    alignment: returnCommentAlignment(),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                    child: getUpvotes(userIndex), 
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: returnAlignment(),
                //This column contains username and comment of commenters
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    //First comment
                    alignment: returnCommentAlignment(),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                    child: RichText(
                        text: TextSpan(
                            style:
                                TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20.0),
                            children: <TextSpan>[
                          TextSpan(
                              text:
                                  'HarperEvans1: ', //will be a username from firebase
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                              recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                                ..onTap = () {
                                  print(
                                      'This will take to profile of that person');
                                }),
                          TextSpan(text: 'Nice photo!'),
                        ])),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    //Second comment
                    alignment: returnCommentAlignment(),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                    child: RichText(
                        text: TextSpan(
                            style:
                                TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20.0),
                            children: <TextSpan>[
                          TextSpan(
                              text:
                                  'trevorwilkinson: ', //will be a username from firebase
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                              recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                                ..onTap = () {
                                  print(
                                      'This will take to profile of that person');
                                }),
                          TextSpan(
                              text:
                                  'Panda Panda Panda Panda Panda Panda Panda Panda Panda Panda Panda Panda Panda Panda'),
                        ])),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    //view more comments
                    alignment: returnCommentAlignment(),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                    child: RichText(
                        text: TextSpan(
                            style:
                                TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 20.0),
                            children: <TextSpan>[
                          TextSpan(
                              text:
                                  'view more comments', //will take to the comments
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                              recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                                ..onTap = () {
                                  Navigator.push(
                                  context, 
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => CommentPage(posts[userIndex], usernames[userIndex])
                                    ),
                                  );
                                }),
                        ])),
                  )
                ],
              )
            ],
          ));
        });
    }
  }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you have nothing triggering a rebuild from Firebase. You need to return a `FutureBuilder` or `StreamBuilder` in your `getUpvotes` function. That will get notified of changes in the cloud and trigger a re-build.

Here's something to get you started. Return this instead in your `getUpvotes` method and complete the stream portion of the `StreamBuilder`

```
StreamBuilder(
    stream: Firestore.instance.collection...// finish this part to get your snapshot of total upvotes from your collection,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
         if(snapshot.hasData) {
     return RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20.0),
        children: <TextSpan>[
          TextSpan(
              text: upvotes[index].toString() + ' upvotes',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
              recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                ..onTap = () {
                  print('This will take to upvoters of the photo');
                }),
               ],
             ),
          );
         }
   else {
    // handle no data
   }
 },
);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. So I tried doing what you said, however the behaviour is still the same; the database updates, but the screen doesn't until I either hot refresh or if I go on another page and go back on it. This is what I added in the stream:

stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('uploads')
      .doc(usernames[index]).collection('images').snapshots(),

But it still doesnt update the widget asynchronously. Did I do something wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: And just noticed some more weird behaviour. If you look at my incrementFollowers function above, you see the line: `.update({'upvotes': upvotes[index]+1,}); ` . This makes it that the database updates, but the widget doesnt. But if I do: `.update({'upvotes': upvotes[index]++,}); `, the widget updates correctly but the database doesnt. Not sure why that is

Comment: Played around with your solution and I got it. Thank you very much!